# COMException unhandled error when sending an email through Outlook using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, comexception

I have the following code to send emails to people, whose details are retrieved from a database:

```
Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
objOL = New Outlook.Application()
oMsg = objOL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

con = New OleDbConnection("provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=pc;initial catalog=DB1;integrated security=SSPI")
cmd = New OleDbCommand("select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table1 where <condition>", con)
con.Open()
r = cmd.ExecuteReader
While r.Read
    oMsg.Subject = "Subject"
    oMsg.Body = "Hello " & r.Item(0) & vbLf & vbCr & "How are " & r.Item(1) & " and" & r.Item(2) & vbLf & vbCr & " ? "
    oMsg.To = r.Item(3).ToString
    oMsg.Send()
End While
con.Close()
oMsg = Nothing
objOL = Nothing
```

The problem is that after it sends the first email, it gives me an COMException unhandled error, stating that the item has been moved or deleted. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a new outlook message each time through loop:

```
Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem 
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application 
objOL = New Outlook.Application() 

con = New OleDbConnection("provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=pc;initial catalog=DB1;integrated security=SSPI") 
cmd = New OleDbCommand("select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table1 where <condition>", con) 
con.Open() 
r = cmd.ExecuteReader 
While r.Read 
    oMsg = objOL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) 

    oMsg.Subject = "Subject" 
    oMsg.Body = "Hello " & r.Item(0) & vbLf & vbCr & "How are " & r.Item(1) & " and" & r.Item(2) & vbLf & vbCr & " ? " 
    oMsg.To = r.Item(3).ToString 
    oMsg.Send() 

    oMsg = Nothing 
End While 
con.Close() 
objOL = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm retrieving a date in ymd format from the DB. How can I format it within the messsage to dmy? I tried the `Format` method, but the date was replaced by "dd-MM-yyyy" in the mail itself. Any help?

Comment: Custom Date and Time Format Strings
: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: I tried `r.Item(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`, where r.Item(1) is a date in the ymd format. I got a "Cannot convert string to integer" or something of that sort, error. What can I do?